# Is there a stable data migration tool for MongoDB for use with a Nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, devops

I am needing a stable tool or stable package regarding the changes one would make to a MongoDB instance before the rollout of a new release. I have seen tools like Liquibase and Flyway but I am needing something for Nodejs apps. I am trying to automate this process and allow my team to provide self contained scripts that would be distributed to this package (and a provided package built script) or a service that we employ.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the npm package [`migrate-mongo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/migrate-mongo). It allows you to create migrations by simply implementing 2 functions; `up` and `down` so that you're able to patch/unpatch your data.

Comment: Have you used this before? If so what was your experience? I have researched such packages and from constraints and package degradation I could not find one that worked for my implementation.

Comment: I used it for non commercial purposes, and it worked just fine. The repo is maintainable (last published one month ago), so you'll be able to communicate any bugs/issues. However, I haven't faced any problem with that so far.

Answer (score 0):

[db-mongo-migration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/db-mongo-migration) found this package that was recently published and have to say it's really great. Has support for dry-run and batch rollbacks aswell

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).